# how to require authentication on mongos router?

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB router, started from a command-line like this:

```
mongos --configdb mdbc1:27019,mdbc2:27019,mdbc3:27019 --keyFile /root/mongodb-keyfile &
```

I can connect to that without immediately supplying authentication:

```
[root@mdbr1 ~]# mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.15
connecting to: test
```

MongoDB requires that I authenticate myself before it lets me do anything more, but the fact that it lets me connect at all without supplying credentials is a security risk.

How do I make the mongos router require that a username/password combo be passed before accepting the connection?

Regarding the duplicates: Yes, I think this is a duplicate. However, since the question was not answered satisfactorily in either of those duplicates, perhaps it is worth asking again.

To explain further: MySQL, SSH, and similar, require that valid login information be supplied before allowing the user to go any further and ask the server to do anything. However, MongoDB does not appear to do this - I can connect to the server's console and get it to run all sorts of intensive JavaScript, wasting resources and being a nuisance, which really should not be allowed. How do I require a login as the absolute first thing a person does?

Comment: Can you really run intensive javascript, waste resources, and be a nuisance, without being authenticated? And what makes you so sure that there is any security risk at all?

Comment: Yes, you really can.

As a test, I connected to a mongo server, did NOT authenticate, and simply wrote "while(1);" and hit enter.

I watched the system through "top" on another terminal. It went to 100% CPU usage immediately.

Security-wise, this does not let you hack in. But it does make it more likely the server will not be able to carry out its usual duties, making it more likely that correctly authenticated processes will fail because there simply wasn't enough CPU available for them.

Comment: I may be wrong about this. After checking again, I realised I was doing the test from localhost on the Mongo server itself. When I try it from another machine, the other machine's load goes up - not the Mongo server.